# Notice - Array to string conversion error

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having an error on array to string conversion. I think I did everything correctly and looped the variable but it's still giving me the notice.

```
<li>
<a  title="">Full Time</a>
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'db', '12345678', 'db');
$logado = $_SESSION['id_utilizador'];
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT modulo FROM disciplinas WHERE id_utilizador = '$logado' ORDER BY iddisciplinas DESC LIMIT 1");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<a>$row</a>"; //Error in this line
}
?>
</li>
```

So yeah. It just shows the notice. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array returns an array in key value format of the rows and columns, in your case the only key you'd have would be $row['modulo']

Comment: So i have to output it as $row['modulo']?

Comment: Correct, you specifically requested it be returned as an array, so it's a key value array, if you're trying to access the modulo from your row, that's what you need to do., more specifically, `echo <a>{$row['modulo']}</a>`; should work

Comment: echo "<a>$row['modulo']</a>";

Comment: This gives me a syntax error

Comment: It gives you an error because you can't use expressions like that in a string unless they're enclosed in {}'s, see my comment above.

Comment: So how can I do it to output?

Comment: You do see that i commented three times, not two, yes? read all three comments, the answer is in them.

Comment: So shall I do it like this? echo "<a>$row{['modulo']}</a>";

Comment: No? I explained it in  my comment, word for word, in a way you can literally copy and paste six minutes ago, use `echo "<a>{$row['modulo']}</a>";`

Comment: Sorry, Didn't see it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First **print_r($row)** and check if you are getting value, then after you will get the expected result in $row["modulo"], check the snippet mentioned below, if it could solve your query -

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'db', '12345678', 'db');
$logado = $_SESSION['id_utilizador'];
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT modulo FROM disciplinas WHERE id_utilizador = '$logado' ORDER BY iddisciplinas DESC LIMIT 1");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    print_r($row); 
    /***/
    /* Check here if you get any thing in $row, then use as @Zachary mentioned*/
    /* uncomment this line if you get value from print_r($row) */
    //echo $row["modulo"];
    /****/
   // echo "<a>".$row['row']."</a>"; //Error in this line
}

?>
```